# How to trace site requests with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httprequest

I currently have a problem that I can't quite get my head around, so I hope that somebody on here might be able to help.

Lets take a site like this:
http://www.fiatpavan.it/parcoveicoli.php

In the browser you can see what kind of requests this site makes when loaded and to what sources/domains. In this case there are 2 different domains it requests data from:  `fiatpavan.it` and `graphics-server4.gestionaleauto.com`. Now, this is all good, but I have many thousand pages that I want to go through and filter out the ones who make a requests to a specific source.

Is there a way to automate that "lookup" and get a list of what requests are being made by the site?

Comment: Sorry but what does this have to do with Ruby or with Ruby on Rails?  Do you want your rails app to scrape the php site looking for particular kinds of links?

Comment: I just added Ruby because I will be coding the solution in Ruby. But right now its a rather general question, I agree!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a scriptable (headless) browser. Here's a JavaScript example using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org):

```js
// resource_logger.js
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onResourceRequested = function(request) {
  console.log(request.url);
};
page.open('http://www.fiatpavan.it/parcoveicoli.php', function() {
  phantom.exit();
});
```

From the command line:

```
$ phantomjs resource_logger.js
http://www.fiatpavan.it/parcoveicoli.php
http://www.fiatpavan.it/css/styles.css?v=2.6
http://www.fiatpavan.it/prettyPhoto/prettyPhoto.css
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
http://www.fiatpavan.it/js/jquery.lazyload.mini.js
http://www.fiatpavan.it/prettyPhoto/jquery.prettyPhoto.js
http://www.fiatpavan.it/js/jquery.local.js?v=2.02
http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js
http://graphics-server4.gestionaleauto.com/gonline_graphics/4377760_T_53d36d11e0b29.jpg
http://graphics-server4.gestionaleauto.com/gonline_graphics/4572976_T_53d36d53144b2.jpg
http://graphics-server4.gestionaleauto.com/gonline_graphics/4470681_T_53d36d2406fd7.jpg
http://graphics-server4.gestionaleauto.com/gonline_graphics/4062343_T_53d36d48eb4f6.jpg
http://graphics-server4.gestionaleauto.com/gonline_graphics/4281687_T_53d36d34938ac.jpg
http://graphics-server4.gestionaleauto.com/gonline_graphics/4572977_T_53d36d5d4a3b1.jpg
http://graphics-server4.gestionaleauto.com/gonline_graphics/4540811_T_53c4ebe6e5c1b.jpg
http://graphics-server4.gestionaleauto.com/gonline_graphics/4377761_T_5378747d2e1c1.jpg
http://graphics-server4.gestionaleauto.com/gonline_graphics/4188892_T_53d36e6bb31ff.jpg
http://graphics-server4.gestionaleauto.com/gonline_graphics/4221069_T_53d36edd8c721.jpg
http://graphics-server4.gestionaleauto.com/gonline_graphics/4241379_T_53d36f00b8164.jpg
http://graphics-server4.gestionaleauto.com/gonline_graphics/4178839_T_53d36f12c6dea.jpg
http://graphics-server4.gestionaleauto.com/gonline_graphics/4188898_T_53d36f249c437.jpg
http://graphics-server4.gestionaleauto.com/gonline_graphics/4188893_T_53d36eb36b5b1.jpg
http://graphics-server4.gestionaleauto.com/gonline_graphics/4566677_T_53d0c92207ab0.jpg
http://graphics-server4.gestionaleauto.com/gonline_graphics/4175811_T_53d36e858f116.jpg
http://graphics-server4.gestionaleauto.com/gonline_graphics/4574673_T_53d4bda473d1a.jpg
http://graphics-server4.gestionaleauto.com/gonline_graphics/4175793_T_53bbb12f09f65.jpg
http://graphics-server4.gestionaleauto.com/gonline_graphics/4356029_T_53bd02bd1b643.jpg
http://graphics-server4.gestionaleauto.com/gonline_graphics/4356028_T_53bd02d15fb14.jpg
http://www.fiatpavan.it/images/banner_googleplay.png
http://www.fiatpavan.it/images/banner_appstore.png
http://www.fiatpavan.it/images/logo_new_home.png
http://www.fiatpavan.it/images/marchietti/6.png
http://www.fiatpavan.it/images/marchietti/21.png
http://www.fiatpavan.it/images/marchietti/28.png
http://www.fiatpavan.it/images/marchietti/42.png
http://www.fiatpavan.it/images/marchietti/60.png
http://www.fiatpavan.it/images/fe/ico_rss.png
http://connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js
http://www.fiatpavan.it/images/pattern_body_home.png?v=1.1
http://www.fiatpavan.it/images/fe/pattern_corpo.gif
http://www.fiatpavan.it/images/fe/ico_menu_sx.gif
http://www.fiatpavan.it/images/fe/bg_campi_form.gif
http://www.fiatpavan.it/images/fe/bg_bottone_scheda.png
http://www.fiatpavan.it/images/box/bg_usato.png
http://www.fiatpavan.it/images/fe/bg_button_dettaglio.png
http://www.fiatpavan.it/images/fe/bg_button_info.png
http://www.fiatpavan.it/images/fe/bg_button_permuta.png
http://www.fiatpavan.it/images/box/bg_km0.png
http://www.fiatpavan.it/images/freccie.png
http://www.fiatpavan.it/images/fe/pattern_footer.gif
http://www.fiatpavan.it/images/fe/arrow-top.png
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=5.5.5&utms=1&utmn=1200517878&utmhn=www.fiatpavan.it&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1920x1200&utmvp=400x300&utmsc=32-bit&utmul=de-de&utmje=0&utmfl=-&utmdt=Parco%20Veicoli&utmhid=1661598644&utmr=-&utmp=%2Fparcoveicoli.php&utmht=1409579764694&utmac=UA-69527-41&utmcc=__utma%3D92154637.1862396724.1409579765.1409579765.1409579765.1%3B%2B__utmz%3D92154637.1409579765.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B&utmu=q~
http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/W2xi4Tmu0YA.js?version=41#channel=f321c29d9c&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fiatpavan.it
https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/W2xi4Tmu0YA.js?version=41#channel=f321c29d9c&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fiatpavan.it
https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?client_id=542911519092465&domain=www.fiatpavan.it&origin=1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FW2xi4Tmu0YA.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df1a3f170ec%26domain%3Dwww.fiatpavan.it%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.fiatpavan.it%252Ff321c29d9c%26relation%3Dparent&response_type=token%2Csigned_request%2Ccode&sdk=joey
http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like_box.php?app_id=542911519092465&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FW2xi4Tmu0YA.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df6dfabca%26domain%3Dwww.fiatpavan.it%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.fiatpavan.it%252Ff321c29d9c%26relation%3Dparent.parent&color_scheme=light&header=false&height=187&href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FFiat-Pavan%2F165510546824760&id=fb-iframe&locale=it_IT&sdk=joey&show_border=true&show_faces=true&stream=false&width=292
https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like_box.php?app_id=542911519092465&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FW2xi4Tmu0YA.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df6dfabca%26domain%3Dwww.fiatpavan.it%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.fiatpavan.it%252Ff321c29d9c%26relation%3Dparent.parent&color_scheme=light&header=false&height=187&href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FFiat-Pavan%2F165510546824760&id=fb-iframe&locale=it_IT&sdk=joey&show_border=true&show_faces=true&stream=false&width=292
https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/y4/r/B18dVCfTbA0.js
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-frc3/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/581511_428344043874741_1845523211_n.jpg?oh=28fd20dc57f938fe5b3adbd5ba6d5e31&oe=54605C4A&__gda__=1416507819_4674c67c822c0e6530aa300a2150962e
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-1/c0.14.50.50/p50x50/9573_10151332481280636_362800646_n.jpg?oh=8fb5b25afb2b0f3502e30f980246ce8f&oe=547568F9&__gda__=1416595941_69b7cd122fc5fca24ee98340e9587b0a
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-1/c50.50.621.621/s50x50/1146607_492482014180042_648683217_n.jpg?oh=761e8dce4f06bb14cf34bb289879d200&oe=54701323&__gda__=1415691442_d77df72bec27fce4dd20d770d1595297
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpa1/t1.0-1/c0.0.50.50/p50x50/63047_1624062446591_1794195_n.jpg
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/c66.66.828.828/s50x50/579240_114958701973059_1273103507_n.jpg?oh=fcf3405fade9194204da46aa9fef0de0&oe=5468D053&__gda__=1415644515_cae14ba72f4550b293b830a76ee7dae5
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-1/c0.0.50.50/p50x50/10395856_888923357800652_2940834727321073921_n.jpg?oh=0c0133dd897f9d82c6230b1b7ee5b117&oe=54666862&__gda__=1416589126_f130e40019fd03839104e54f2332ee28
https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/y1/r/LVx-xkvaJ0b.png
```